# cambiar el txt de los botones de actionsheet

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angularjs, ionic

llevo varios dias buscando una solución a mi problema y no doy o ya estoy cegada y no veo que estoy haciendo mal.

Estoy trabajando con ionic y angular.
He creado una actioncheet, donde tengo dos botones uno de cancelar y otro de bloquear usuario, cuando se abre el actionsheet aparecen esos dos botones todo bien, aprieto el botón de "bloquear usuario" y llamo a una función para añadir en una base de datos el registro del usuario que quiero bloquear, perfecto funciona, al volver abrir el actionsheet con los botones el texto se abre con el botón de "desbloquear usuario" perfecto aprietas y me elimina de la base de datos el registro de ese usuario bloqueado bien todo como quería. Que pasa si volvemos abrir el actionsheet por tercera vez debería aparecer el botón con el texto "bloquear usuario" pero sigue apareciendo el texto "desbloquear usuario" ahí mi problema, perooo si salgo de esa pagina y volvemos a entrar el boton aparece como debería aparecer con el txt "Bloquear usuario" por lo que entiendo que si se refresca la pagina si funciona.

aquí mi código html:

```
<ion-button (click)="presentActionSheet(product_item)"  >
        <ion-icon slot="start" ios="ellipsis-horizontal" md="ellipsis-vertical"></ion-icon>
</ion-button>
```

js:

```
async presentActionSheet() {
    var userbloqueado = this.bloqued_user_list.find((i) => i.bloqued_user == this.chat_item.seller_user_id);
    if (userbloqueado != undefined) {
      this.text = 'Desbloquear usuario'
    } else if (userbloqueado == undefined) {
      this.text = 'Bloquear usuario';
    }

    const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({

      buttons: [
        {

          text: this.text,
          icon: 'person-remove-outline',
          handler: () => {
            if (userbloqueado != undefined) {
              this.Deleted_bloqued_user();
            } else {
              this.Bloquear_user();
            }
          },
        },
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          icon: 'cancel',
          data: {
            action: 'cancel',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    await actionSheet.present();
  }
```